# The code is slower when I use OpenMP

Tags: openmp, pragma, reduction

I am trying to parallelize a code using OpenMP, I'm just using two reductions and I don't understand why my OpenMP code is slower than the sequential code. It is just a split of the array between the processors. Does anyone have any idea why it is like this?

```
float visibleLength;
float *k = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
int visibleLines = 0;


k[0] = data.y[0] / data.x[0];
visibleLength = data.y[0];

omp_set_num_threads(12);
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:visibleLines,visibleLength)
for (int i = 1; i<N; i++) {
    k[i] = fmax(k[i - 1], data.y[i] / data.x[i]);
    if (k[i] > k[i - 1]) {
        visibleLines = visibleLines + 1;
        visibleLength = visibleLength + data.y[i] - k[i - 1] * data.x[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you measure the time? Where are your measurement results?

Comment: I'm using the function clock(); for measuring the time and the result here ` //END CLOCK
 end = clock();
 printf("End Clock \n");

 printf("\n visibleLines = %d \n \n", visibleLines);
 printf("\n visibleLength = %f \n \n", visibleLength);

 time_spent = (double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
 printf("\n Time Expend = %f \n \n", time_spent);`

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm appears to be sequential because you are using the result of the previous iteration `k[i-1]`. I also don't think the `ordered` clause would fix it. You should change the algorithm.

Are you sure your results were correct at all when you tried the parallel run? I would be surprised if they were.

Comment: yes the results are okay, but more slowly if you comment the #pragma you have the sequential code and I try to paralyze it using this #pragma